# mysql curdate off by one

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out why when I update my database with CURDATE() it always sets it to tomorrow's date.

Server time is:
Mon Sep 10 16:53:47 MDT 2012

Update looks like:
UPDATE map SET size=500007292,kb="476.84 MB",lastupdate=CURDATE(),version="1621" WHERE id = "5d903cd6863015dff2c2a1b65346d107"

The last time I updated, earlier today, it set the date to 9/11/2012

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What does "SELECT CURDATE()" say?

Comment: Also check "show variables like 'system_time_zone'"

Comment: So that's Moscow time.  Not sure how that happened but I put in a support ticket to get it fixed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSD seems to be [Moscow time](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/eu/msd.html).  It is tomorrow there already.